# Pausing in batches during a foreach loop?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script to migrate 500+ DNS records to Windows 2008 (from '03) and then manipulating attributes - all via DNSCMD (builtin MS DNS tool).

Anyways - there is a limitation in DNS where if you do things "too fast" it starts choking on itself - I've seen this before in my old DOS scripts.

That said, how would I batch up a foreach loop?

Like for example (in laymans terms w/ scripting)

```
$records = C:\myfile.txt

foreach ($record in records) {
     MyFunction (only to the first 20 records)
     start-sleep 2
     MyFunction (to the next 20 records)
... etc .... 
    }
```

Is that possible?  If so how would you approach it?  I guess I could add a simple `start-sleep 1` after `MyFunction`, but with 500+ records, times many functions, that's gonna take a VERY long time.  :(  I think batching them is the best in terms of efficiency we've found from the DOS world.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're reading them from a file, you can batch them up using -ReadCount:

```
Get-Content C:\myfile.txt -ReadCount 20 |

foreach {
 foreach ($record in $_) 
   { MyFunction $record }
 start-sleep 2
 }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Does the -ReadCount automatically restart the processing all over again for the next 20, etc.??  I'm new to PS.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes.  It will read the file in batches of 20 records, and for each batch, process those twenty records, sleep for 2 seconds, and then go back for another 20 records and do it all over again until it's gone through the whole file.

Comment: Just re-factored my script and it's running wonderfully - and logging all successes!  Thank you for your help.  Powershell gets more and more amazing the more I ask.  :-)  You just saved me over an hour of waiting.  :)